# Is this Arduino NANO counterfeit?

Tags: arduino-nano, counterfeit

Today i bought my second NANO(First one was made of Gravitech).I have some doubts that if it is a counterfeit product.I have noticed some points & they are as follows.

1)No "NANO" printed on the top of the board.

2)The atmega328p is in MLF package.

3)A diode soldered on the back side of a board is not properly positioned.

4)No version is printed anywhere.

5)The word "ICSP" not printed near the ICSP header.

6)No pin marking(white dot) for ICSP pin#1.

The seller is a very reputable one in India.That's why i can't be 100% sure if it is a counterfeit product.
I am attaching some pics.Please take a look & give your valuable feedback.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x44qY.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am just guessing when I say: the mlf package is no problem, the missing label "nano" on top and missing version might indicate a first test run. The misalignment is bad, that should not happen. The soldering quality is good. Is that a real ftdi chip, it probably is or else it stops working in windows. Overall it seems a genuine arduino board, but it might be a production test run.

Comment: Thanks a lot,that is a news of relief!
I tested the FTDI chip & it is still running correctly(without getting bricked).Also i have a counterfeit FTDI & some real FTDIs laying around.I compared this one with those side by side.Also from the physical appearance,this one looks genuine.

Comment: Have you seen the newest photos? https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano Two of the three photos have the mlf package, the white button, the yellow foil on the usb connector. After they made your board, they decided to add the name "nano" on top and the dot at pin 1 of the icsp connector.

Comment: Where did you find the arduino nano with mlf package in the Arduino page?I can see only two images both with tqfp packages!!And in my case,seems like they didn't decide to put the name nano on it

Comment: This is the same as the package in your photo: https://store-cdn.arduino.cc/uni/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x375/f8876a31b63532bbba4e781c30024a0a/a/0/a000005_iso.jpg

Comment: strange!
I can't find this photo in arduino.cc website...But the direct link you provided is working fine!!